# Replacing document.getElementById with jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code snippet:

```
$('#selector1,#selector2').change(function(){
    checkDate(document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")));
});
```

The above works fine, but I want to use jQuery's `$` instead of `document.getElementById`. So, I tried this but it gives me a javascript error: `TypeError: valueToTest is undefined`

```
$('#selector1,#selector2').change(function(){
    checkDate($("#" + $(this).attr("id")));
});
```

Comment: `valueToTest` is not part of the code in your question. Are you sure that is the code relevent to the error?

Comment: why not just use $(this) as arguement to the checkDate?

Comment: Just use `checkDate($(this));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `document.getElementById('id')` you get the reference to the DOM node itself, whereas calling `$('#id')` will return a jQuery object that has a reference to the DOM node that matched the selector (if there's an element with the given id). With the former you can access its properties directly (`this.id`, `this.value`, etc), whereas with the second you need to use the jQuery functions (`.prop()`, `.val()`, etc).

If you wanted to pass a jQuery object you'd likely also need to make changes to your `checkDate` function to avoid errors where you're accessing properties directly, and those properties no longer exist on the jQuery object.

With that said, this line:

```
checkDate(document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")));
```

is far more complicated than it needs to be. You've already got a reference to the element - `this` - so accessing its `id` and passing it to `document.getElementById()` to gain another reference to it makes no sense. You could simply do:

```
checkDate(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a jQuery object as parameter to `checkDate()` instead of a DOM element, to get the DOM element you can do this:

```
$('#selector1,#selector2').change(function(){
    checkDate(this);
});
```

Comment: Doing `$(this)[0]` is nonsense, it's exactly the same as just using `this` except it adds a bunch of unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet:

```
document.getElementById($(this).attr("id"))
```

The above code returns a HTML `DOM Object`. If you use `$(this);` you will not get the `DOM Object` but a `jQuery object`. So, you need to modify it like `$(this)[0]` or simply `this` to get the `DOM Object` and your code would work perfectly fine.

**CODE:**

```
$('#selector1,#selector2').change(function(){
    checkDate($(this)[0]);
});
```

OR

```
$('#selector1,#selector2').change(function(){
    checkDate(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById retrieves a (one) DOM node while jQuery returns a jQuery object that actually is an array of DOM nodes. Hence, to replace

```
var element = document.getElementById($(this).attr("id"));
```

using jquery, do this

```
var element = $($(this).attr("id"))[0];
// or
var element = $($(this).attr("id")).get(0);
```